# Access denied for Instagram API large image

Tags: xml, api, instagram

Why do I get access denied for the large version of this image?
http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/b375adbe291611e3b7bc22000aeb43ae_7.jpg

Medium and thumbnail works fine:
http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/b375adbe291611e3b7bc22000aeb43ae_6.jpg

This started happen yesterday. First with one user like this one, where only one among many images not working. And with one user where almost all images were not working.

The image is not deleted from Instagram, and except for when a image is deleted, this has not happend before.

Anyone with idea of why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting _7 with _8 at the end, like this: http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/b375adbe291611e3b7bc22000aeb43ae_8.jpg

In general you should not rely on those URL to be stable over time. You should fetch them on demand.

Comment: I'm experiencing this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711879/querying-tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-how-to-avoid-private-photos The problem I see though is that if I fetch each photo url everytime, I'll go through my 5k api query per hour in minutes! I'm currently using Realtime to sync to my local DB and displaying from there. Maybe I'm missing something?